# I have to Subtract the Sum of the same values in a column of every month in SQL

Tags: sql, count, sum, percentage, subtraction

Im a begginer in SQL. I have three columns: date_ref, evaluation_name, count_evaluation_name.

Table:

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGumX.png)

Result:

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jLjP.png)

I need to **Substract** The **SUM** of all **promo**  for the **SUM** of all **deprecator** from the column evaluation_name. But I need it per month (and then, show it as a percentage) and then get the result for the last 3 months
like the image.

I dont really have a code, trying to work out how am I going to do it. But the result is the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be supplemented with a description of the tables and (or) an expression for creating test data. For example, so

```
create table test(evaluation_name varchar(20),date_ref varchar(10),count_evaluation_name int);
insert into test values
 ('Promo'     ,'01DEC2022',254)
,('Neutral'   ,'01DEC2022' ,89)
,('Deprecator','01DEC2022' ,80)
,('Deprecator','01JAN2023' ,49)
,('Neutral'   ,'01JAN2023' ,81)
,('Promo'     ,'01JAN2023',178)
,('Deprecator','01FEB2023' ,76)
,('Promo'     ,'01FEB2023',236)
,('Neutral'   ,'01FEB2023',101)
;
```

Try this query example

```
with t as( 
-- totals by months
select substring(date_ref,3,3) mon
 ,sum(case when evaluation_name='Promo' then count_evaluation_name else 0 end) Promo
 ,sum(case when evaluation_name='Neutral' then count_evaluation_name else 0 end) Neutral 
 ,sum(case when evaluation_name='Deprecator' then count_evaluation_name else 0 end) Deprecator
from test
group by substring(date_ref,3,3)

union all

-- totals by table
select 'Total' as mon
 ,sum(case when evaluation_name='Promo' then count_evaluation_name else 0 end) Promo
 ,sum(case when evaluation_name='Neutral' then count_evaluation_name else 0 end) Neutral 
 ,sum(case when evaluation_name='Deprecator' then count_evaluation_name else 0 end) Deprecator
from test
)
select *
  ,Promo-Deprecator as Total
  ,(Promo-Deprecator)*100.0/(Promo+Neutral+Deprecator)  as 'Percent'
from t
```

Result with your data

| mon | Promo | Neutral | Deprecator | Total | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEC | 254 | 89 | 80 | 173 | 41.134751773049 |
| FEB | 236 | 101 | 76 | 160 | 38.740920096852 |
| JAN | 178 | 81 | 49 | 129 | 41.883116883116 |
| Total | 668 | 271 | 205 | 463 | 40.472027972027 |